# Create an Array of Objects with Firebase Async Dictionary Download (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, firebase

I'm new to Swift.  I have been having trouble downloading Firebase dictionaries and turning them into an array of objects.

What am I doing wrong with the syntax below?  I've spent the last two days unsuccessfully trying to figure this out.  The following gives me an index out of range error.  Is this because the Firebase Dictionary hasn't finished downloading yet or is my for in loop sytax flawed?  Perhaps both?  Thanks.

```
 // Array of Location Objects
 var locationsArray:[Location] = [Location]()

 var ref = Firebase(url: "<MYFIREBASEURL>")
 var dictionaryOfRecommendations:[NSDictionary] = [NSDictionary]()
 var currentlyConstructingLocation:Location = Location()

 func getLocationData() {

    let titleRef = self.ref.childByAppendingPath("events")
    titleRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        var tempDict = [NSDictionary]()

        for item in snapshot.children {

            let child = item as! FDataSnapshot
            let dict = child.value as! NSDictionary
            tempDict.append(dict)
        }

        self.dictionaryOfRecommendations = tempDict

    })

    // Parse data from Firebase

    // Loop through each dictionary and assign values to location object
    var index:Int
    for index in 0...dictionaryOfRecommendations.count {

        // Current Json dictionary
        let jsonDictionary:NSDictionary = self.dictionaryOfRecommendations[index]

        self.currentlyConstructingLocation.title = jsonDictionary["title"] as! String!
        self.currentlyConstructingLocation.locationsLatitudeArray = jsonDictionary["latitude"] as! Double
        self.currentlyConstructingLocation.locationsLongitudeArray = jsonDictionary["longitude"] as! Double

        // Append to Locations Array and start new Location
        self.locationsArray.append(currentlyConstructingLocation)
        self.currentlyConstructingLocation = Location()

    }

    // Notify the MainViewController that the Locations are ready.
    ...
}
```

Comment: Firebase is asynchronous - you cannot operate on Firebase data until you actually have that data. With your code, the loop through each dictionary code will execute WAY before firebase has returned it's data; local code in your app is much faster than the internet! The solution is to process the data within the Firebase withBlock section. You can keep the for index in loop, just enclose it in a function and call that function from within the Firebase block, after the self.dictionary line. Give that a try and if it doesn't work, update your post with updated code and we will craft an answer.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you!  That was the point in the right direction I needed.  I create a function to split out the parsing of data and called that function in the Firebase block.  I also figured out the error in my for/in loop that was causing the out of range error.  Posting correct code below for others to benefit from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the updated correct code for the question above based on Jay's helpful guidance:

// Model to download location data for events.

```
//Firebase reference
var ref = Firebase(url: "<MYFIREBASEURL")

var locationsArray:[Location] = [Location]()
var dictionaryOfRecommendations:[NSDictionary] = [NSDictionary]()
var currentlyConstructingLocation:Location = Location()

 func getLocationData() {

    let titleRef = self.ref.childByAppendingPath("events")
    titleRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        var tempDict = [NSDictionary]()

        for item in snapshot.children {

            let child = item as! FDataSnapshot
            let dict = child.value as! NSDictionary
            tempDict.append(dict)

        }

        self.dictionaryOfRecommendations = tempDict
        self.ParseFirebaseData()

    })
}

func ParseFirebaseData() {
    // Parse data from Firebase

    // Loop through each dictionary and assign values to location object
    var index:Int
    for index in 0...dictionaryOfRecommendations.count - 1 {

        // Current Json dictionary
        let jsonDictionary:NSDictionary = self.dictionaryOfRecommendations[index]

        self.currentlyConstructingLocation.title = jsonDictionary["title"] as! String!
        self.currentlyConstructingLocation.locationsLatitudeArray = jsonDictionary["latitude"] as! Double
        self.currentlyConstructingLocation.locationsLongitudeArray = jsonDictionary["longitude"] as! Double

        // Append to Locations Array and start new Location
        self.locationsArray.append(currentlyConstructingLocation)
        self.currentlyConstructingLocation = Location()

    }
}
```